# Typescript Pick - pick property fields

Tags: typescript

Say I have an interface such as:

```
interface MyInterface {
   myProperty: {
     one: number
     two: string
   }
}
```

How can I `Pick` `myProperty` fields? Is this possible?
The desired result should be:

```
{
   one: number
   two: string
}
```

So that when using the type:

```
type MyType = ...

const t: MyType = ...
t.one = ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use a type query if you want to get the type of the member :

```
interface MyInterface {
    myProperty: {
        one: number
        two: string
    }
}

type MyType = MyInterface['myProperty']

const t: MyType = {
    one: 1,
    two: '2'
};
t.one = 3
```

Although refactoring to a separate type as suggested by another answer may be the saner way to go if possible.

Comment: It's a one-time thing, private to the JS module and used on a single line of code, so I think I'll go this route. Thanks!

Comment: Titian, is there also a way to "go back" to the original interface? I'm just curious

Comment: @LppEdd tl;dr; None that I know of maybe a hackish way. The type of the property has no idea where it originated. You can build a more complex type that extract the property type and also adds extra information to keep the originating type in there, but you would have an extra dummy property like `_parent` to keep the type information, so it's not something I would use unless absolutely unavoidable

Comment: Thank you! Anyway I won't do anything like that, I was just curious

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate interface for myProperty:

```
interface MyProperty {
   one: number
   two: string
}

interface MyInterface {
   myProperty: MyProperty
}

const myObject: MyProperty = { one: 1, two: "2" };
```

And then use it throughout your code.

Answer (score 1):

Separate them out into 2 separate Interfaces

```
interface MyProperty {
  one: number
  two: string
}

interface MyInterface {
  myProperty:MyProperty
}
```